# Simulate Band Bending and Band Alignment in Semiconductors

Tags: electricity, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics

Are there softwares (simple ones preferred) where we can simulate the band alignments and band bending of a p-n junction, where we can vary properties of the junction materials such as carrier concentration, band gaps, thickness etc?

This will be really useful in class for visualizing how the various properties affect a p-n junction. I'm particularly interested in p-n junctions in photovoltaic devices.

Answer (score -2):

I have a Python package "eq_band_diagram" for 1D equilibrium band diagrams: [README](http://pythonhosted.org/eq_band_diagram/), [source code](https://github.com/sbyrnes321/eq_band_diagram/).

Comment: Resource recommendation questions have [special expectations](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed/4698#4698) on [physics.se], and this answer needs revision to meet standard.